# YouTube force full screen on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I've taken a look at the YouTube API and it seems quite clear (for security reasons) that the player (embedded or not) does not allow YouTube video to automatically initiate full screen once loaded.

I wondered if there was a way to do this using Javascript to act as if the user had pressed the full screen button?

Any ideas shared would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do this but you can maybe make it fill the whole screen take a look http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/cTdMx/embedded/result/. Maybe you can do what you want using the [Youtube JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)

Comment: Does YouTube strictly use Flash for it's player skin or is it an actual element? Or even better, is there a way to make a click on the screen on a selected pixel worked out by the script in Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't use the YouTube player API to initiate fullscreen programatically.

This is because the underlying issues with fullscreen in flash and html5 video would make such an api method seriously error-prone.

Official response to back me up:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube-api-gdata/Tyv3vTw0RQk/449KahYVNFYJ